# Using of external es6 module inside angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, es6-modules

I have new angular cli project that created using ng new and i extract the webpack configuration using ng eject.

So now i have an external es6 module and i want to use it inside one of my components.

Let us assume the project structure like this:
`src\app\customModule` this folder has two files `myModule.ts`, `myModule2.ts`.

I have create new entry point and chunk for this module and call it `customeModule` and make sure it downloaded before the main chunk.

Here is `myModule.ts` file:

```
module MyModule{
    export interface CarProperties {
          name:string;
          price:number;
    }

    export enum CarType{
          BMW,
          Hyundai
    }
}
```

And `myModule2.ts` file:

```
module MyModule{
    export class Car {
         private speed:number;

         constructor(){
              console.log("New car has been initialized");
         }
    }
}
```

So Assume i will use it in app.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(){
   console.log(MyModule);
}
```

Once i run npm run start or npm run build, i saw the new chunk with the network tab but still get **MyModule is undefined**

Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you declare this module in app.module.ts?

Comment: @Pterrat It's not angular module, it has not ngModule decorator. it's an external library that use typescript.

Comment: Could you give me your @import in app.component.ts?

Comment: `import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';`

Comment: Could you try to add import { MyModule } from './customModule/myModule'?

Comment: You cannot import from it like angular way because it's not a ngmodule. anyway i tried your way and it gave me an error, File is not a module.